# Android Imagebutton small images

Tags: android

I have made 3 different images, each with sizes of 48x48, 72x72, 96x96 and 144x144. I imported them into eclipse and put them in the folder they are supposed to go into (drawable-mdpi etc. )

These images are each on `ImageButton` and all of them are in a `LinearLayout` which is under a `SeekBar`.

But when I start the app, the images are so small!

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_previous" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_play" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_next" />

</LinearLayout>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
```

I want them to be twice the size than what they are currently. What can I do to make them bigger?

Answer (score 0):

First when you have your imageButton click in GraphicLayout Background  set drawable(and pick your image from folder)  i think you setting Src not background, then you can do things like Scale type and pick fitXY or change your imagebutton width and height, that all.